# how to verify some user in sudoers when we add user using Shell script AIX Unix?

Tags: shell, unix, aix

I want to ask about how to verify the user in list that already exist in file sudoers and the script no add the user again if already exist in sudoers.

And the adduser.sh script like below :

```
# List user using another file (name file is users)
for i in $(cat users); do
# add user from list user file
useradd $i
# Change inital Program /usr/bin/ksh to /usr/bin/ksh93
chsh $i /usr/bin/ksh93
echo "user $i added successfully!"
# add user to file sudoers
echo $i 'ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /HAapps/sudoers

# create user password and adding 123
echo $i:$i"123" | chpasswd
echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"
done
```

After I run the script twice adduser.sh, there are information like below :

```
3004-689 User "swakus1" exists.
user swakus1 added successfully!
Password for user swakus1 changed successfully
```

and the result in file sudoers like below :

```
swakus1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
swakus2 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
swakus3 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
ario1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
ario2 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
swakus1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
swakus2 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
swakus3 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
ario1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
ario2 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: Use `getent password "$i"` or `grep "^$i:" /etc/passwd` to first see if the user exists. If the user does, continue the loop.

Comment: @bishop, I will learn first how to comment sorry. But I already try and failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getent password <username>
```

to check if user exist in the system. With command

```
sudo -U <username> -l
```

will list the user privileges based on `/etc/sudoers` file and can be used to get info if user is already in sudo or not